# How to install two different versions of same rpm and make them work parallely

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Currently I am trying to install a rpm secured_soft_2.0.0.rpm and i am 
unable to install it as we already have secured_soft_1.3.0 installed.

Requirement is that we need to have both the versions installed.

Complexities :

These package inturn have dependent rpm's (lot of them ) and all these
interdependent rpm's also have versions
ex: secured_soft_1.3.0 works only with packages which are of version 1.3, 
and secured_soft_2.0.0.rpm work only with dependecies of version 2.0 only.
So all these dependencies also need to be reinstalled and even these 
dependenies should be parallely installed, without deleting old.

Finally , both these versions contain shared libraries and these shared 
lib's do not have version numbers in their name.

```
#rpm -ivh secured_soft_2.0.0.rpm
error: Failed dependencies: 
init-class >= 1.4.17.1-1 is needed by secured_soft_2.0.0.rpm    
init-connection-interface >= 2.0.11.0 is needed by secured_soft_2.0.0.rpm  
init-logger >= 2.0.11.0 is needed by secured_soft_2.0.0.rpm  
init-security >= 2.0.11.0 is needed by secured_soft_2.0.0.rpm
```

As i have specified we already have secured_soft_1.3.0.rpm installed and
above dependencies are also available but of different version.
So we need the to install above dependencies and also need the old version's 
of dependencies for the old rpm's to work

ex : secured_soft_2.0.0.rpm has libArt.so libSec.so and so on 
which are copied to /usr/lib

Similarly secured_soft_1.3.0.rpm also has libArt.so libSec.so and so on
which are already available in /usr/lib

I tried to rename the so's but still iam not able to install.

Is it possible to change the location for these so's and get the things done
Is there any way we can do it.

At the moment, iam stuck here and would need advice on this
Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Since the programs use the same filenames, and you need to put them on the same machine, you *might* be able to move the older version to another directory tree and make it work *there*.

You can do this with many applications which do not have compiled-in pathnames.

For instance,

- install the older version (this sounds like where you are starting from)
- use `rpm -ql` for each of the packages containing unversioned executables, libraries and associated files.
- use tar to capture an archive of those files, relative to `/usr` (but *omitting* directories not *owned* by the packages).
- create a new directory, e.g., `/usr/local/myapp` and untar the older version there.
- update configuration files in the new location as needed

For applications such as this, I would run in a script that updates `PATH` (and perhaps sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) to force the program to run from the new location.  You can verify if this works using tools such as [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) and [`lsof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof), i.e., by looking for the files that the program opens.

Once you have the older version working properly in the new location, you can uninstall its rpms and install the new version of the application.

*Caveat:*  If the newer package is copied from a newer version of the operating system, however, the task is likely to be beyond your ability, whether or not you choose the alternative approach of recompiling the newer packages to fit on the existing system.

Building new/custom packages is one route to recompiling the newer version.  If you have the source-RPMs for each part, that is a starting point:

- extract the files from the source-RPM, e.g., using a script such as `unrpm` (see for example *[HowTo: Extract an RPM Package Files Without Installing It](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html)*), and
- copy those extracted files to their as-expected locations in your build-tree, e.g., `$HOME/rpmbuild/SOURCES` and `$HOME/rpmbuild/SPECS`
- modify the spec-file to use the alternative location
- build the new/modified package using the modified spec-file.

Comment: The older version and all its dependencies are already installed and new versiona dn its dependencies have to be installed.is there a way that i can write a new spec for these latest rpm's and dependecies  and get them installed in seperate folder other than /usr /etc and get them working. Currently, the issue is installing the newer version and iam not able to install because of the lower version dependencies and also older version of this package already installed. Iam also  new to these rpm realted thing , would appreciate if some one can advice me on how to rebuild the new rpms .

Comment: To do that, you would have to recompile everything.  From the information in the question, that sounds like a lot of work.  It depends on where you want to spend your time.

Comment: Yes, i need to recomplile and recreate all the latest dependent rpm's and the main rpm, so that the conflict doesnt arise. Is there a way to that. i found some videos in youtube on building the rpm's,But couldnt find any which talks about editing the rpm and repacking it. Is there a way to do that?\

Comment: Use fpm: https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm
It's very simple and powerful tools for create/modify package.

Comment: There is no link provided for examining `secured_soft_2.0.0.rpm`, and OP has not indicated whether there are pathname-dependencies.  Lacking that analysis, there's no guarantee that fpm (or similar tools) would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

No, out of the box, you cannot.

I'd highly recommend looking into [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), where you can throw each one into their own container and let them take care of all their dependency problems.