# RPM Spec - How to Allow Multiple Versions

Tags: rpm, specifications

Take the kernel rpm for example, it allows multiple versions to be installed concurrently on a system. What exactly in the spec file permits that?

I want to package a project that already exists as multiple versions with distinct installation prefixes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**YUM**

Found the way to have yum install instead of update. There's a configuration directive to do so. From man yum.conf:

**installonlypkgs**

> List of package provides that should only ever be installed, never
>   updated. Kernels in particular fall into this category. Defaults to
>   kernel, kernel-bigmem, kernel-enterprise, kernel-smp, kernel-debug,
>   kernel-unsupported, kernel-source, kernel-devel, kernel-PAE,
>   kernel-PAE-debug.
>
> Note that because these are provides, and not just package names,
>   kernel-devel will also apply to kernel-debug-devel, etc.
>
> Note that "kernel-modules" is not in this list, in RHEL-6, and so
>   anything providing that is updated like any other package.

**installonly_limit**

> Number of packages listed in installonlypkgs to keep installed at the
>   same time. Setting to 0 disables this feature. Default is '3'. Note
>   that this functionality used to be in the "installonlyn" plugin, where
>   this option was altered via tokeep. Note that as of version 3.2.24,
>   yum will now look in the yumdb for a installonly attribute on
>   installed packages. If that attribute is "keep", then they will never
>   be removed.

Tested and confirm it replicates the behavior with kernel. When updating or installing, yum will not update (remove) the old package.

Note that the package name in the list must be exact, it doesn't consider wildcards. So there a way to do it, and likely automate the process in the rpm's **%post** script.

Answer (score 3):

What would permit it would be to ensure that none of the file/pathnames in the different versions of the package are the same.  Packages which do this generally use either different directory names or different filenames (such as appending the version number to one or the other).

I gave a more elaborate answer in [How to install two different versions of same rpm and make them work parallely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255132/how-to-install-two-different-versions-of-same-rpm-and-make-them-work-parallely/33255714#33255714)

Comment: Okay this works fine for the RPM part but yum for instance will want to upgrade the package instead of installing the other version in parallel.
How do I get yum to behave like it does on a kernel rpm?